# Tkinter button starts program after closing the main window

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am trying to make GUI for data acquisition from arduino. I want to enter file name and start data acquisition after pressing the button. At the moment when I press the button nothing happens but when I close the window it starts. I would like the window stay open.

My code is as follows:

```py
import serial
from tkinter import *
import csv

def start_measurement():
    global file_name
    file_name = entry_1.get()

my_window = Tk()
label_1 = Label(my_window, text = "File name: ")
entry_1 = Entry(my_window)
button_1 = Button(my_window, text = "Save", command = start_measurement)

label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_1.grid(row=0, column=2)

my_window.mainloop()

arduinoData =serial.Serial('COM15', 9600)

while (True):
    while(arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline().decode().split(',')
    x=float(arduinoString[0])
    y=float(arduinoString[1])

    print(x, y)

    with open(file_name + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
        writer.writerow([x, y])
    f.close()
```

Comment: Remove `my_window.mainloop()` and inside `while True` say `my_window.update()`. Though it is better to move the logic inside a function in a separate thread or so as `while` loop will block `mainloop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer from my side.

---

**Firstly let me mention the issues that you did in your code:**

1. If you want the gui to perform the function you want it to then the whole code should be inside these two statements according to your code:

- First Statement: `my_window = Tk()`
- Second Statement: `my_window.mainloop()`

2. You want that when you click the button the program executes. According your code the button only do this and nothing else.

```
global file_name
file_name = entry_1.get()
```

---

**Now why does it happen? Why does it execute when your window closes?**

Here is the answer. As I mentioned in the `1` error above whole code should be inside if you want it to execute along with the window. Your code comes after the tkinter `mainloop` which excludes it from the gui program. So until the gui is running, the `mainloop` doesn't execute the code lines below and when it is closed the loop ends and then the rest is executed and thus you get the problem that you mentioned.

---

**How to do the thing you want?**

Here you want this code to be executed when you click the button, so this code should be inside the function `start_measurement()` as it is what the button is supposed to do.

```
arduinoData =serial.Serial('COM15', 9600)

while (True):
    while(arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline().decode().split(',')
    x=float(arduinoString[0])
    y=float(arduinoString[1])

    print(x, y)

    with open(file_name + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
        writer.writerow([x, y])
    f.close()
```

I would say that **cut** this code from its current place and then add it inside the `start_measurement()` function.

---

Now if I make the correction and write the code again. Then this would be the final result.

```
import serial
from tkinter import *
import csv

def start_measurement():
    global file_name
    file_name = entry_1.get()
    arduinoData =serial.Serial('COM15', 9600)

    while (True):
        while(arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
            pass
        arduinoString = arduinoData.readline().decode().split(',')
        x=float(arduinoString[0])
        y=float(arduinoString[1])

        print(x, y)

        with open(file_name + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
            writer.writerow([x, y])
        f.close()

my_window = Tk()
label_1 = Label(my_window, text = "File name: ")
entry_1 = Entry(my_window)
button_1 = Button(my_window, text = "Save", command = start_measurement)

label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_1.grid(row=0, column=2)

my_window.mainloop()
```

---

Please give this a try and do tell me if it worked or not because when I tried it, it was working just fine. Post a comment if you feel you can't understand something here.

Thank You! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear and step by step explanation. It was perfectly helpful. I tested the code and it saves data when I press the button. But I noticed small problem when the program runs and I click anywhere in the window it states that stopped responding.

Comment: Well, to be honest I don't have any answer to this as I encounter same problem with many other GUI programs. I never found a working solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have the actual process after the mainloop. That is the reason that when you close the program the rest of your code starts. You should have everything before the **my_window.mainloop()** and in a function. Basically the mainloop is a while loop that constantly updates the GUI to adapt to changes therefore cannot reach the rest of your code until it is broken (the window is closed).

Comment: Would be nice if you could show how its done.